# Compile time error while accessing public variable in java main method

Tags: java

Can some one help what is wrong in this code? I have a parent class and child class created in java. I created a Parent class instance in Child class static main method. The public method is accessible, but not the public variable. Initially I thought this is something related to static scope. But that does not seem to be the issue. Because I am explicitly creating an instance of Parent class in the main method of child class. So ideally both variable and method should be accessible as I am explicitly creating an instance of Parent class in the static context. Strange thing is method is accessible without errors, but not the variable. Why the compiler is OK with the method but not with the variable? Ideally the error should be shown for both or not at all.
Both classes are in different package. But public scope is not going to be a problem even if the classes are in different packages I hope. Please find the below two classes..

```
package com.learning.scjp.examples;

public class ParentClass {

    public String parentClassPublicVariable = "parentClassPublicVariable";

    public  void parentClassPublicScopeMethod(){
        System.out.println("parentClassPublicScopeMethod");
    }
} 
=================================================================
package learning.access.classes;

import com.learning.scjp.examples.ParentClass;

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass();
        parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable;//This statement shows compile time error "not a statement"
        parentClass.parentClassPublicScopeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable;` to do?

Comment: you're not setting the data to any variable. It should be something like `String variable = parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable;` you can't just write it the way you did. You have to USE it somehow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't put an action after accessing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In general a statement in java is something that contains enough information to compile to translate the code into a meaninful action, something that can be executed by JVM.

Usually it can be:

- Declaration statement  (Example: `int i = 0;`)
- Expression statement   (Example: `i++`)
- Control flow statement (Example: `for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)`)

The line: 
`parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable`

is basically meaningless, it has no action, therefor compiler doesn't understand what should be done, its an error from the compiler's standpoint. Hence you have "not a statement" compilation error.
You can read about the statements [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/types-of-statements-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access it just do it this way :-

```
class ParentClass {

    public String parentClassPublicVariable = "parentClassPublicVariable";

    public  void parentClassPublicScopeMethod(){
        System.out.println("parentClassPublicScopeMethod");
    }
} 

public class Try extends ParentClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass();
        System.out.println(parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable); // You can print it.
        parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable = "StackOverflow"; // You can even reassign variable.
        System.out.println(parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable);
        parentClass.parentClassPublicScopeMethod();
    }
}
```

Basically the line parentClass.parentClassPublicVariable; itself is useless and compiler is not able to understand it hence the error it had nothing to do with access modifiers or inheritance as you assumed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now.